# How to replace (change) values in cells DB SQLite (Android)?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a question - I have finished the database (SQLite), with updates, I analyze the structure and see whether I need to add new data or change the value in existing positions database. So I have a question - is it possible to replace the values ​​in the entire line at once (that is, in all cells (which are the same id) columns), or there is a possibility to replace the values ​​for each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the id of the row to update, you can use the `SQLiteDatabase.update()` [(docs here)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

As you can see in the `update()` function, you use `ContentValues` to udpate the row, and provide the row id in the `whereClause` of the function. Inside the `ContentValues`, you can put new values of columns, as you'd normally do for an insert:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.putString("row1Name","value1");
cv.putString("row2Name","value2");
```

etc. The update call would be something like

```
db.update("table_name", cv, "row_id=?", new String[]{""=rowId);
```

Comment: Sorry, but the field "row_id =?" should be such in any way? That is my query should look like?            db.update(DBOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, cv, "row_id=?", new String[]{idChangeLocation+""});

Comment: That is correct. The `?` is a placeholder for one variable, which we provide in the `String[]{}` that follows the whereClause

Answer (score 0):

You can use the on conflict replace unique constraint in your table creation.

If a row conflicts with the constraint then it will be replaced, for example:-

```
create table people (
    _id integer primary key autoincrmement,
    person_id integer,
    name text,
    age integer,
    unique (person_id) on conflict replace
)
```

What this will do is replace the row if you try to insert with a person_id that already exists.

Check it out here http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html